# Keeping lots of time data in sql schema

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, time

I'm learning sql and as a exercise, I'm trying to understand what the best way of keeping time data in sqlite would be. As an example, I can create a database which keeps track of cars and car parts and time logs of when they fail. Background schema: there is a car (which can breakdown) and a car has parts (which could fail) and I'd like to log this data on when either the car or one of its parts were operational or failed.

My schema code is here (and [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkjyEzKkcwwu1RDCBmYaEb/1)):

```
create table car (
name varchar,
id int primary key
);


create table car_part (
car_id int,
part_name varchar,
part_id primary key
);


create table last_checked_time_log (
checked_time datetime,
failed_or_operational boolean,
car_id int,
foreign key(car_id) references car(car_id),
primary key (checked_time, failed_or_operational, car_id)
);
```

Is this schema the good way to do it?

Currently, the table last_checked_time_log can only hold either a car or a car_part. But I would like it to be be able to hold both since either a car or a car_part can fail (I'm don't care that a car fails because of a car part. I just want it simple as it is - full car failed or one car_part failed).

Also, with the current schema, I think that if I add a lot of cars (lets think 1000 cars in a city) and all the respective car parts, then the last_checked_time_log will become huge in a few days. Is there a better way to make this or is this just how it will work in this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which DBMS you are using? E.g.: sqlite, mysql, postgresql, mssql? Are you trying to solve problem in "sql in general"? Can you use a fiddle to share your code? E.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkjyEzKkcwwu1RDCBmYaEb/0 ?

Comment: Hi, I am using sqlite. I don't have code.  I just want to understand a structure conceptually so that I can tackle that later

Comment: Your `table ...` statements are **your code**. Look at [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkjyEzKkcwwu1RDCBmYaEb/0) I created for you. Is it your **code**? You can edit this fiddle and add for your question as illustration. Than you can again describe your problem

Comment: Oh okay. I modified the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jkjyEzKkcwwu1RDCBmYaEb/1) (Thank you!). So I made this structure schema. I wanted to know how I would be able to add a car_part_id to the last_checked_time_log table. Because I want it to be either a car or a car part but right now, according to how I made it, it can only be one of them.

The other question is - how would i make it better because i think that the last_checked_time_log table will become huge in a few days if it carried real cars and car parts data.

Comment: Excellent! I suggest you: a) edit your question, b) add code from created fiddle **and** link to it, c) add problem description. It will be a high-quality question that have high a probability to be answered

Comment: Edited! I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: OK. It's looking much better now! A little advice: don't ask  broad questions as "the better", "the best", "the correct" and such. It's preferred to ask in a way: "I need this [requirement]. I tried it so [some code] and got that [results]. My problem is .. [describe why results are not in required form]"

Comment: Side note: you *really* want to use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, not `INT PRIMARY KEY` in your table definitions: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid